# Extract p-value from anova() from comparison of two linear models in R

Tags: r, extract, anova

My apologies for not including enough information to properly access the issue.  Anyway,I want to compare different pairs of linear models and record their p-values into a table.  Where my troubles lie is that I cannot extract only the p-value.

```
TC <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=6)
    ML5 <- 1:5
for(B in ML5) {
    Coop <- anova(M6,Models5[[B]])$"Pr(>F)"
    TC[1,B] <- Coop
}

 >Coop
   NA 2.041767e-05
```

So how do I only put the number into the table and not the NA into the table?

Thanks a million!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract p-value from aov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366506/extract-p-value-from-aov)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need quotation marks:

```
pvalue <- anova(m2,m1)$"Pr(>F)"
```

You can access the second element of pvalue using normal bracket subsetting:

```
pvalue[2]
```

So in your example I believe you'll use

```
Coop <- anova(M6,Models5[[B]])$"Pr(>F)"[2]
```

(Although without access to M6, I can't be totally sure).

The `str` command is very useful in this sort of situation, to figure out what kind of object you're dealing with:

```
str(myanova$"Pr(>F)")
```

Comment: OK now I get the error, "Error in T21Comp[A, B] <- Coop : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: Hard to interpret that without a reproducible example.

Comment: `myanova$"Pr(>F)"` is a vector, not a single number. People get caught by surprise because the `NA` here are invisible in the printout of an intact `anova` object (which is really just a `data.frame`), but still exist and become visible when subset. The error probably means you are assigning it to something that has fewer spaces than `Coop` takes up. Print out `T21Comp[A,B]` and `Coop` (by typing them at the command line) and see how big each one is. Subset the larger one accordingly (or change the length of the smaller one).

Answer (score 0):

Using `mtcars` data from R (I would prefer the solution suggested by @Drew Steen)

```
myanova<-anova(lm(mpg~cyl,mtcars),lm(mpg~cyl+disp,mtcars))
pval<-summary(myanova)[1,6]
```

**Updated as per question:**

```
models1<-lm(mpg~cyl,mtcars)
models2<-list(lm(mpg~cyl+disp,mtcars),lm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp,mtcars),lm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+drat,mtcars))
myp1<-lapply(models2,function(x) anova(models1,x))
myp2<-lapply(myp1,function(x)summary(x)[1,6])
> myp3
[1] "   0.05419  " "   0.09891  " "   0.09661  "
```

**Add:If you are using "$"Pr(>F)"**

```
  myp2<-lapply(myp1,function(x)x$"Pr(>F)")
  myp3<-sapply(myp2,function(x) as.data.frame(x)[2,1])
    > myp3
    [1] 0.05418572 0.09891469 0.09661222
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aov():

```
anova_a <- aov(response ~ time + Error(subject), data = all_data)

f_value <- unlist(summary(anova_a)[[2]])[9]
```