# To extract the variable with its P-value<0.5 in a dataframe after an MANOVA Test

Tags: r, manova

I have a data frame containing an "independent variable" and a series of
potential "dependent variables". I'd like to find the "dependent
variable" with the strongest association to my "independent variable".

I've carried out a MANOVA in R as follows:

```
mydata<-iris #produce a data frame
                                               #containing my dependent variables
anovatest<-manova(cbind(Sepal.Length,   Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width)~as.factor(Species),data=mydata)
```

I can access the results of this using the following:

```
summary.aov(anovatest)
```

I want to prduce a dataframe where i need only the variables with Pr(>F) <0.05

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a sample of your data. Also read [how to make a good R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: there is a similar problem in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366506/extract-p-value-from-aov/35739836 you can just try summary and get what you need

Comment: I am not getting the output as per the above replies.